# How are ERC 721 metadata secured?

Tags: erc-721, meta-data

If erc721 tokens store the metadata off chain, how is that information secured?  If I mint a jpeg as an NFT, using erc721, and the uri just points Tia file, how is that file secured?  What prevents someone from changing that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IPFS to store files. It is the best NFT metadata storage solution

If metadata is stored on a center server, it will be impossible to avoid modification and will not have any credibility.